# H2 File mode, error while opening new connections on existing file db

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to create a H2 DB to a file.
a small module first runs that creates the file and the schema and populates it with data.
While doing this this the H2 jdbc url used:

```
jdbc:h2:file:c:\\Yogesh\\TestH2Db;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST\\;SET   SCHEMA TEST\\;
```

A DDL script for the schema is run and then on this I am loading up some data using RunScript class.
After the loadup this module stop (The JVM dies/is no longer running).

A second module, tries to use this pre-created data based to run some tests.
To connect to this DB i am trying to use this url:

```
jdbc:h2:file:c:\\Yogesh\\TestH2Db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST\\;SET   SCHEMA TEST\\;
```

Basically the same url but with IFEXISTS=TRUE added.
A JdbcConnectionPool is create based on this URL.

```
protected JdbcConnectionPool initConnectionPool(String user, String pwd,
        int maxConn, String jdbcUrl) {
    System.setProperty("h2_jdbc_url", jdbcUrl);
    JdbcConnectionPool connpool = JdbcConnectionPool.create(
            jdbcUrl, user, pwd);
    connpool.setMaxConnections(maxConn);
    return connpool;
```

and when the rest of the module does a getConnection on the above created JDBC Connection pool, it fails and seems to be creating the same objects that I had created in the Init module again.

I have tried it without the INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST\;SET   SCHEMA TEST\; to no avail

Edit: To add the stack Trace

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
[Have a create view statement here that fails cant give out the SQL statement, 
however note that this SQL statement ran fine 
when i used RunScript tool to init the DB schema; 
What i don't understand is while doing get connection the 
connection Pool why are objects 
being inited again, the Schema creation script is not part of the 
INIT part of JDBC Url]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:491)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:2798)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfMore(Parser.java:809)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:778)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateView(Parser.java:4281)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:3749)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:324)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:255)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepare(Parser.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepare(Session.java:388)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepare(Session.java:375)
    at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:632)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:305)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:109)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:93)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:181)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:315)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getPooledConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:341)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:226)
    at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
    at junit.db.utils.InitH2DB.getConnection(InitH2DB.java:45)
    at test.DBLoader.DBLoader.main(DBLoader.java:21)
```

Comment: How does it fail (exception message, stack trace)?

Comment: Added the Stack Trace, just a thought is the INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST\\;SET   SCHEMA TEST\\; causing any problems?

Comment: Could you copy the exact error message including SQL statement? It's really not helpful if you change the message.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Found the problem. The schema init script that i had, was generated using get_ddl from Oracle. a few views had lines truncated at 80 chars. While the DB was being inited and RunScript used no errors were reported. However while a new connection was being made using the JDBC connection pool, the DB was throwing errors for these invalid objects. I cannot paste the actual DDL's but there as sample representation of what was happening: Contd...

Comment: CREATE TABLE EMP
(
  EMP_NO    NUMBER, EMP_NAME  VARCHAR2(256),
  EMP_ADDRESS  VARCHAR2(256),
  EMP_ADDDATA1 VARCHAR2(256),
  EMP_ADDDATA2 VARCHAR2(256)
);

create or replace view "Emp_V"("EMPLOYEE_NAME","EMPLO
YEE_NUMBER") 
as (select emp_name, emp_no from emp);
Note: the break in the EMPLOYEE_NUMBER. This was causing the DB heartburn while creating new Connections. I tried to debug the issue till JdbcStatement.executeInternal() but couldnt fathom why it didnot report issues when run through Script Runner and got an issue while creating new connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error was because of an incorrect script used to create teh H2 schema.
See comments below the question for more details.